# Gstreamer rtsp pipeline for videostream error

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp

I have an issue when trying to connect to an rtsp videostream using gstreamer. The videostream originates from a IP camera.

Using the same rtsp address in vlc and opencv (without gstreamer) works as it should.

This pipeline is used when testing:

```
GST_DEBUG=1 gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:password$@192.168.2.1:554/ch1/main/av_stream ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

This error occurs when running the pipeline:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://admin:password192.168.2.1:554/ch1/main/av_stream
0:00:03.105886290  6248 0x559fd7cf1520 ERROR                default gstrtspconnection.c:1046:gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response: failed to connect: Error resolving “admin”: Name or service not known
0:00:03.105953476  6248 0x559fd7cf1520 ERROR                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5047:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<rtspsrc0> Could not connect to server. (Generic error)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(7893): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

If I use a password that is not correct, I also get the same error message. This makes me believe that gstreamer does not manage to log in to the ip camera videostream.

For trail and error purpose, I tried this pipeline without and usr or password:

```
GST_DEBUG=1 gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.1:554/ch1/main/av_stream ! decodebin ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.2.1:554/ch1/main/av_stream
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Unauthorized
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6540): gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Unauthorized (401)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rtspsrc` has properties for authentication.

Try using

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc user-id=admin user-pw=password location=rtsp://192.168.2.1:554/ch1/main/av_stream ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Comment: i have same issue can you please help me in this I am getting error Failed to connect to RTSP server 192.168.1.250:554 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681412/vlc-could-not-connect-to-rtsp-url