# gstreamer rtsp unauthorized while VLC can play

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I have a working pipeline begins with :

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://Test_Map:T3$t1ng_2022_Map@x.x.x.x:zzzz/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/101

which gives Unauthorized error. But vlc can open same stream .

any idea?

gst-launch should open the rtsp

Comment: Maybe the "$" is interpreted by the shell. Try putting quotes around the uri.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gstreamer rtsp pipeline for videostream error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75070785/gstreamer-rtsp-pipeline-for-videostream-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the user-id and user-pw argument with proper ""

than it will work.