# VLC could not connect to Rtsp URL

Tags: android, vlc, rtsp

This is my Activity

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var url: String = "rtsp://192.168.1.250/xxx.mov"

    private lateinit var libVlc: LibVLC
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var videoLayout: VLCVideoLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        libVlc = LibVLC(this)
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(libVlc)
        videoLayout = findViewById(R.id.videoLayout)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        mediaPlayer.attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false)

        val media = Media(libVlc, Uri.parse(url))
        media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false)
        media.addOption(":network-caching=600")

        mediaPlayer.media = media
        media.release()
        mediaPlayer.play()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        mediaPlayer.stop()
        mediaPlayer.detachViews()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        mediaPlayer.release()
        libVlc.release()
    }
}
```

I am trying to Live Stream using given code i am getting below Error while  launching app

> 2023-03-09 12:35:51.519 16435-16578 VLC
> com.rovedashcam.android              E  [b40000750b63d640/40c2] libvlc
> demux: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.1.250:554/xxx.mov
> 2023-03-09 12:35:51.522 16435-16578 VLC
> com.rovedashcam.android              E  [b40000751b637620/40c2] libvlc
> stream: Failed to connect to RTSP server 192.168.1.250:554 2023-03-09
> 12:35:51.526 16435-16578 VLC
> com.rovedashcam.android              E  [b40000751b637620/40c2] libvlc
> stream: cannot connect to 192.168.1.250:554 2023-03-09 12:35:51.526
> 16435-16578 VLC                     com.rovedashcam.android
> E  [b40000751b637620/40c2] libvlc stream: VLC could not connect to
> "192.168.1.250:554". 2023-03-09 12:35:51.526 16435-16578 VLC
> com.rovedashcam.android              E  [b40000757b647f60/40c2] libvlc
> input: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.250/xxx.mov'.
> Check the log for details.

Main Problem: what I am seeing mediaPlayer.stop Method takes long time to stop and release this reason I am not stopping media player

while I am able to play it from browser.
can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong with this ?

Comment: why do you call `media.release()` before you actually play it?

Comment: I have follow above example https://lindevs.com/play-video-file-using-libvlc-on-android do we need to remove it i am facing problem in stop mediaPlayer.stop()

Comment: does this link work with desktop VLC?

Comment: yes its worked  so thing is that  we have two mode of live view video mode so its working fine in  desktop app when we refresh link and we change command from video to photo mode.

Comment: @snachmsm  can you help me in trouble shoot this issue .

Comment: Are you running this in the emulator or on a real device?

Comment: @zomega yes i am running emulator and real device both having same issue

Comment: @MARSH Did you declare internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: have you copied all sources from [HERE](https://lindevs.com/display-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-using-libvlc-on-android) and still doesn't work? maybe this IP isn't "achievable", havie you tried to ping it?

Comment: @snachmsm yes tried same example but still its not working  problem is mediaplayer.stop takes to much time to stop video and when i tried from browser its working fine when i switch camera to refresh url from browser.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @MARSH Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No bro i am not able to find solution you also have different camera channel ?

Comment: @mohammedahmed When i use http URL  it is working very fine try to make instead of rtsp use http URL